How can we sign multiple TXes for sequential broadcast/consideration?
Lets say I have a manual signing system and want to sign a bunch of TXes in a row. However, these transactions should only be broadcast in sequence. For example, I want to Mint then Transfer. Can Solana allow me to sign both the mint and the transfer tx but enforce the mint happens first on chain?

If you want the transactions to happen sequentially, but don't want to wait for confirmation that the first tx to be finished before sending the second, consider using JITO bundles:
https://jito-labs.gitbook.io/mev/searcher-resources/bundles
With bundles you can sign both txes as you normally would and pass them to the bundle. You can configure the order of the txes and have it finish all-or-nothing, so if the first tx fails the second will not send.
There is a small tipping fee required to use bundles.

Yes, you can make use of the signAllTransactions method to sign and send your txs separately,
Using the react wallet adapter, you'd fetch the signAllTransactions method from the useWallet hook
const { signAllTransactions } = useWallet();

const initializeMintTx = ....;

const transferTx = ...;

if (!signAllTransactions) return;

signAllTransactions([initializeMintTx, transferTx]);

// send your transactions using anchor wallet or the connection object

If you are using UMI,
    const mint = generateSigner(umi);
    const initMintTx = await await createNft(umi, {
        // snip
    }).buildWithLatestBlockhash(umi);

    mint.signTransaction(initMintTx);

    const transferTx = await transferV1(umi, {
        // -- snip
    }).buildWithLatestBlockhash(umi);

    await umi.identity.signAllTransactions([initMintTx, transferTx]);

    signAllTransactions([tx]);

// send your tx

web3.js would also follow a similar structure

Hurm, that appears to just use a js library to loop through an array of transactions and sign them (assuming certain preconditions). There isn't any on-chain instructions there ensuring the initMintTx can't be entirely dropped.

Dropped? I'm not sure I follow

If we sign via res = signAllTransactions([initializeMintTx, transferTx] then we can res.pop(); signedTransfer = res.pop(); broadcast(signedTransfer) thus broadcasting the transferTx without broadcasting the MintTx.
The sought after solution is a method to sign two TXes and have an on-chain mechanism enforce order of broadcast. This might not be possible without a program on chain to support the logic.

If there's a possibility that the tx might fail, inside you try-catch block, you can poll the tx signature to make sure that inittializeMintTx was successful.
